# Handlebars passing data to existing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Is it possible to just pass data to existing html element , because I have a lot of JQ plugins  I need to use on that element and when Im creating template like this

```
var source = $("#some-template").html(); 
var template = Handlebars.compile(source); 
$('body').append(template(data));
```

with appending element to body my plugins wont work on dynamically created element ?